# Keyboard hides layout components inside ScrollView Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

This is the layout contains the components and I tried

EDIT 1: More explanation
The layout does not scroll up as expected when I focus on any edit text. What happens is edit text got the focus, it shows up the key board (which hide nearly half of the layout) and I can not scroll up to see other components below it like the radio buttons and last button.

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the manifest with no luck.

FragmentLayout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/newfeedback_padding_maincontainer"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/newfeedback_padding_maincontainer"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/new_feed_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/main_blue_light" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_dr_name_dr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_feedback_items_margin_top"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/dr_name"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="50dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sp_medtype"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg_final"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:minHeight="50dp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_gender"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_feedback_items_margin_top"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_dr_female"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                 />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_dr_male"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sp_govern"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg_final"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:minHeight="50dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sp_specializations"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg_final"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:minHeight="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_phone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_feedback_items_margin_top"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_phone"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:minHeight="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_address"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_feedback_items_margin_top"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="50dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_feedback"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_feedback_items_margin_top"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minHeight="50dp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_feedback_items_margin_top"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_eval3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_eval2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_eval1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                 />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_addfeedbck"
            style="@style/green_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:minHeight="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.FullScreen" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.iii.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        </activity>

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Post only relevant code, and a specific explanation as to what is going on. Though we likely could figure out the issue with this, it makes it difficult for users to benefit from it in the future.

Comment: This is the layout relevant code and the manifest with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: What is happening? What do you want to happen? Which views are being hidden and which views do you not want to hide? It is a ScrollView so some of its children may, inherently, be out of view. I can assume you mean the edittext in focus is out of view, you may need to handle scroll position dynamically. As a general rule if you have far more code than text in your question it isn't following a good format. We don't need to see your entire layout and manifest, just relevant code.

Comment: This is the relevant code. The layout does not scroll up as expected when I focus on any edit text. What happens is edit text got the focus, it shows up the key board (which hide nearly half of the layout) and I can not scroll up to see other components below it like the radio buttons and last button.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I too have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Cant be in full screen mode and resize window same time I guess.